# Counter not updating with email count using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some jQuery that calls some serverside code as a counter to count number of emails sent, problem is even though the jquery call the serverside code, the counter never updates, and just displays the final count.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sendFunction = function() {
        $.post("/path/to/server",
            function(data) {
                if (data !== "-1") {
                    $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-success\">Sent " + data + " emails</p>");
                    setTimeout(window.sendFunction, 500);
                } else {
                    $("#progressSend").hide();
                }

            });
    };
})
```

My serverside code in MVC controller

```
int currentCount = SendMailingListSmtp.PollingCounter;
message = currentCount.ToString();

return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and the code I'm using to actually count number of emails send which is in a foreach loop, but omitted.

```
int counter = 0;

using (var smtp = new SmtpClient()) {
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    var credential = new NetworkCredential {
        UserName = smtpUsername,
        Password = smtpPassword
    };
    smtp.Credentials = credential;
    smtp.Host = smtpHost;
    smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(smtpPort);
    //smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
    smtp.PickupDirectoryLocation = "C:\\Users\\\\Desktop\\Customers\\\\PickUp\\";
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;                     
    smtp.Send(emailMessage);
    counter++;
    PollingCounter = counter;

}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(window.sendFunction, 500);` looks weird.  That method is not defined on the global scope.  It is a var within the document ready function.

Comment: Do some debugging and try to narrow it down to the bit of code that doesn't do what you expect. For example, check if the counting code is getting the correct number. Then check what is being return as json, etc.

Comment: where is your loop, are you initiating count everytime you loop ? i think it is the issue, each time you loop, you set the count to 0 and then increment then loop again, set it to 0 again, then increment, int count =0 should be outside the loop, which I can't see in the code you added.

Comment: I agree @Munzer. I was about to say the same thing!

Comment: The loop works, it increments correctly but the value is never displayed on the client till all the emails have been sent. I cannot find the problem in either VS or chrome, its just the value never get displayed till the end

Comment: An update on this, if I do thread.sleep(1000) it works